# Creating New Keyboard Shortcots fur Lock Screen and Spotlight search

Tags: keyboard, screen-lock

I know the defaults:

- control+shift+power : Lock screen
- command+space : Spotlight

I do NOT want to change these -- they must continue to work.

However, due to severely ingrained muscle memory and the fact that I work on many other sensitive systems in the same day, I need to create two new shortcuts that do the same thing:

- command+L (or similar) : Lock screen
- control+space : Spotlight

How can this be accomplished on OS X?  (simple settings change, or editing DefaultKeyBinding.dict , or via 3rd party software )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) to map key combinations to other key combinations:

`<autogen>__KeyToConsumer__ KeyCode::L, VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE, ConsumerKeyCode::EJECT, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>`

`<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::SPACE, VK_CONTROL | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::SPACE, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>`

See the source for the [key code values](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](http://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml).

Comment: Works well for the most part... but not with Synergy :(

Answer (score 0):

1. First things first:

   - First: The shortcut for Sleep, or Lock Screen is actually <kbd>Shift-Cmd-Eject</kbd> (topmost right key on laptops and Bluetooth Apple-supplied keyboards, top right key on full size USB keyboard).
   - Second: <kbd>Cmd-Space</kbd> is the easiest shortcut to use for Spotlight. You cannot just apply a single key to the shortcut like you can in games.
2. That being said, I would suggest using <kbd>Cmd-Opt-Ctrl-Shift-Z</kbd> (or <kbd>-X</kbd>) for Sleep

   - Go into System Preferences (>System Preferences...) and navigate to the Keyboard Shortcuts pane (>System Preferences...>Keyboard>Keyboard Shortcuts)

     - After testing this, I realized that you actually cannot change the default shortcut for Sleep. However, I do know after testing that there is a shortcut to Shut Down, even though it's not listed on the menu list: <kbd>Cmd-Ctrl-Opt-Function</kbd> (bottom right on laptops and Bluetooth Apple-supplied keyboards, in the middle island of six keys on the full size keyboard)
   - Apple actually does not allow you to have more than one shortcut for each function, otherwise that could possibly cause confusion and/or become a controversy with shortcut on installed applications.

I wish you the best of luck.

-Frazier

Comment: Control-shift-power / control-shift-eject is the shortcut for display sleep. And you can change the Spotlight shortcut to just a single F-key.

Comment: @LauriRanta On the laptops, Command-control-function-option is for computer sleep, and I didn't know you could change spotlight...